# ERROR de sintaxis en los IF y en los SWITCH

Tags: java

//Programa de IñakiRC

Devuelve varios errores de sintaxis: "**error: cannot find symbol" e "ilegal start of type**" señalando los if y los switch. ¿Qué sucede?

```
public class Akerra{
public static void main(String args[]){
int versos=1;
   while(versos<=4){ //Cuatro versos

         introduccion();
         estribillo();
         partefinal();

   versos++;
   }      
}

public static void introduccion(){
   switch(versos){
         case 1:
            System.out.println("Akerra ikusi dugu baratzean jaten.");
            System.out.println("Makila ikusi dugu aker hori jotzen.");
         break;
         case 2:
            System.out.println("Sua ikusi dugu makila erretzen.");
            System.out.println("Ura ikusi dugu sua amatatzen.");
         break;
         case 3:
            System.out.println("Idia ikusi dugu ur hori edaten.");
            System.out.println("Soka ikusi dugu idi hori lotzen.");
         break;
         case 4:
            System.out.println("Sagua ikusi dugu soka hori eteten.");
            System.out.println("Katua ikusi dugu sagua harrapatzen.");
         break;
   }
}
public static void estribillo(){
      if (versos>3){
         System.out.println("Katuak sagua, saguak soka,");
      }
      if (versos>2){
         System.out.println("Sokak idia, idiak ura,");
      }

      if ( versos > 1){
         System.out.println("Urak sua, suak makilak,");
      }

      if ( versos > 0){
         System.out.println("Makilak akerra, akerrak artoa,");
      }

}

public static void partefinal(){
   System.out.println("Akerra ken.");
   System.out.println("Baratzetik akerra ken,");
   System.out.println("Ken, ken, ken, ken.");
   System.out.println("");
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Eso ocurre porque estás usando la variable `versos` en las funciones `introduccion` y `estribillo` sin tenerla declarada dentro del scope de la función o sin ser recibida por parámetro de entrada de la función.

Así es como deberían estar declaradas tus funciones:

`public static void estribillo(int versos)`

`public static void introduccion(int versos)`

El código arreglado quedaría así:

```
public class Akerra{
public static void main(String args[]){
int versos=1;
   while(versos<=4){ //Cuatro versos

         introduccion(versos);
         estribillo(versos);
         partefinal();

   versos++;
   }      
}

public static void introduccion(int versos){
   switch(versos){
         case 1:
            System.out.println("Akerra ikusi dugu baratzean jaten.");
            System.out.println("Makila ikusi dugu aker hori jotzen.");
         break;
         case 2:
            System.out.println("Sua ikusi dugu makila erretzen.");
            System.out.println("Ura ikusi dugu sua amatatzen.");
         break;
         case 3:
            System.out.println("Idia ikusi dugu ur hori edaten.");
            System.out.println("Soka ikusi dugu idi hori lotzen.");
         break;
         case 4:
            System.out.println("Sagua ikusi dugu soka hori eteten.");
            System.out.println("Katua ikusi dugu sagua harrapatzen.");
         break;
   }
}
public static void estribillo(int versos){
      if (versos>3){
         System.out.println("Katuak sagua, saguak soka,");
      }
      if (versos>2){
         System.out.println("Sokak idia, idiak ura,");
      }

      if ( versos > 1){
         System.out.println("Urak sua, suak makilak,");
      }

      if ( versos > 0){
         System.out.println("Makilak akerra, akerrak artoa,");
      }

}

public static void partefinal(){
   System.out.println("Akerra ken.");
   System.out.println("Baratzetik akerra ken,");
   System.out.println("Ken, ken, ken, ken.");
   System.out.println("");
}
}
```

Comment: ok, sólo queda un error: "method introduccion in class Akerra cannot be applied to given types". ¿qué sucede? Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, pégame aquí el código de error completo.